# Change Background

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android and I have an image in my drawable folder which I was able to load as my background, now I would like to draw on top of the background but havent been able to, how can achieve this... I have the following, all i want is to draw a circle on top of the image background

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/my_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:background="@drawable/background">        
</FrameLayout>
```

---

```
        //MY ACTIVITY
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main);
         }
       //IN MY VIEW CLASS
            public GameView(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
         canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the image as background use ImageView in Absolute Layout.Enter code to set img as background :

---

### android:background="@drawable/icon1"

Now you would be able to have circle over the image view

Answer (score 1):

use ImageView in xml file & set what u want to draw on background.

Comment: Well in reality I want to be able to draw it programatically, say i want to draw a green circle, then a white circle but hide the green circle.. Also I am having trouble laying it on the FrameView, its so hard to accomodate the imageView where I want.. for example I want the imageView to appear on the right of the center but ImageView always comes up in the top left.. :(

Comment: so u can use relative layout then put frame layout inside the relative.you can set where u want to set imageview in relative lay.Also u can create the Image view dynamically.with what u want like green circle then white circle..:)

Comment: Where would I do this in my View Class under OnDraw?